# How to scroll webview horizontally inside ViewPager?

Tags: android, webview, scroll, android-viewpager

I have a viewpager, where each page has to show a different WebView. This WebView should allow horizontall scrool, and I want to swipe to next page when the scroll finishes.

I've searched, and find some solutions, but nothing I did resolve this issue. I have a CustomViewPager and a CustomWebView for trying to handle scroll events.

This is my code:

**Custom ViewPager**

```
public class WebViewPager extends ViewPager {

    public WebViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean canScroll(View v, boolean checkV, int dx, int x, int y) {
        if (v instanceof ExtendedWebView) {
            return ((ExtendedWebView) v).canScrollHor(-dx);
        } else {
            return super.canScroll(v, checkV, dx, x, y);
        }
    }
}
```

**Custom WebView**

```
public class ExtendedWebView extends WebView {

    public ExtendedWebView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public ExtendedWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public boolean canScrollHor(int direction) {
        final int offset = computeHorizontalScrollOffset();
        final int range = computeHorizontalScrollRange() - computeHorizontalScrollExtent();
        if (range == 0)
            return false;
        if (direction < 0) {
            return offset > 0;
        } else {
            return offset < range - 1;
        }
    }   
}
```

**ScreenSlidePagerActivity**

```
public class ScreenSlidePagerActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    class MyPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private List<Fragment> fragments;
        private List<String> titles;

        public MyPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
            this.fragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
            this.titles = new ArrayList<String>();
        }

        public void addItem(String url, String title) {
            Fragment myFragment = new WebViewFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putString("url", url);
            myFragment.setArguments(args);
            this.fragments.add(myFragment);
            this.titles.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return this.fragments.get(position);
        }

        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return this.titles.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return this.fragments.size();
        }
    }

    private MyPageAdapter pageAdapter = null;
    private WebViewPager pager = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        pageAdapter = new MyPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        pageAdapter.addItem("url1", "WebView 1");
        pageAdapter.addItem("url2", "WebView 2");
        pageAdapter.addItem("url3", "WebView 3");

        pager = (WebViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

        pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(pageAdapter.getCount() - 1);
        pager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);
    }
}
```

**Layout of the activity**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <com.example.viewpagerexample.WebViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="6dp"
        android:paddingTop="0dp" >

        <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
            android:id="@+id/pager_header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:paddingBottom="0dp"
            android:paddingLeft="0dp"
            android:paddingRight="0dp"
            android:paddingTop="0dp"
            android:textColor="#000" />
    </com.example.viewpagerexample.WebViewPager>

</LinearLayout>
```

**UPDATE**
The accepted answer only worked if I put this parameter in the CSS of my web page:

`display: table;`

Apparently, without this parameter the WebView is not able to calculate the width of its content.