# Android WebView computeHorizontalScrollOffset is always 0 and built-in zoom controls not displaying

Tags: android, scroll, webview

**UPDATED QUESTION:** (16th Nov 2016) what in the HTML would make the WebView stop returning valid values for "canScrollXXX"/computeXXXXRange/computeXXXXScrollOffset/computeXXXXScrollExtent and stop the built-in zoom controls displaying.

**My Requirement**

I have a WebView inside a ViewPager. I would like to have it that the WebView scrolls left and right until it meets the edge of the HTML and then the ViewPager can take over.

**My Issue**

There are a few questions already on SO about this issue.  They all make use of

```
"computeHorizontalScrollOffset"
```

but this ALWAYS returns 0 for me.

Furthermore, the following also always returns 0.

```
final int range = computeHorizontalScrollRange() - computeHorizontalScrollExtent();
```

***Does anyone know why the "computeHorizontalScrollOffset"  always returns 0?***

I have also noticed the built-in zoom controls are not showing, even though i have told them too.

**Existing research**

The SO questions i have already looked at are the following (among others)

- Scroll webview horizontally inside a ViewPager ([Scroll webview horizontally inside a ViewPager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7774642/scroll-webview-horizontally-inside-a-viewpager))
- How to scroll webview horizontally inside ViewPager ([How to scroll webview horizontally inside ViewPager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26535702/how-to-scroll-webview-horizontally-inside-viewpager))

**My code**

Here is my WebView layout. I have tried a FrameLayout and an LinearLayout and there is no difference.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</FrameLayout >
```

In my fragment for my ViewPager page, i instantiate the WebView as follows

```
    webView = v.findViewById(R.id.webView);
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebChromeClient(...);
    webView.setWebViewClient(...);
```

**UPDATE** (16th Nov 2016)

I have actually narrowed this down to be caused by the *contents* of the WebView.

If i use a different URL in my WebView I see the built-in zoom controls and on moving the view around I see that "canScrollXXX" is now returning true and computeXXXXRange/computeXXXXScrollOffset/computeXXXXScrollExtent appear to all have proper values and the offset even changes depending on where i am in the view. With my desired HTML contents these methods don't return valid values and the built-in zoom controls are never visible.

Therefore I need to be able to determine *what* in the HTML would make the WebView stop returning valid values for "canScrollXXX"/computeXXXXRange/computeXXXXScrollOffset/computeXXXXScrollExtent and stop the built-in zoom controls displaying.

Comment: Did you have any luck tracking down what in the HTML stops the WebView from returning valid values?